# Rest assured test case is failing due to floating point confusion

Tags: java

I am running with a test case in rest assured but it is failing with below error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed. JSON path
>   zero_base.herebyBreakdown doesn't match. Expected: with toString()
>   "[{value=-365305.5f, value=-75133.81f, value=79750.484f, value=0.0f}]" 
>   Actual: [{value=-365305.5, value=-75133.81, value=79750.484, value=0.0}]

while, Actual results from post man are:

```
{
    "value": -365305.5066
},
{
    "value": -75133.816
},
{
    "value": 79750.4868
},
{
    "value": 0
}
```

Can someone please help me out here !

Comment: A [mcve] would be a great help to help identifying the root cause and possible solution.

Comment: You didn't even post your assertion code?

Comment: Hi juan, here it is  -> [{value=-365305.5f}, {value=-75133.81f}, {value=79750.484f}, {value=0.0f}]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you compare floats to doubles.

Please make sure that compared values are the same type, or even better in case of floating-point numbers you should take into account that the resulting numbers might not be equal - and compare them with some error margin.

(For example in restassured/hamcrest  there is sth like "closeTo", `org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo`, for example:

```
assertThat(actual, is(closeTo(6, 0.5)));
```